# differential equations exercise

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A(t) \in R^{n\times n}$, $A(t)$ continuous, such that $A(t+1)=A(t)$ for all $t \in R$; if $x(t)$ is a solution defined on $R$ of the system
$x'(t)=A(t)x(t)$ such that $x(1)=-x(0)$, prove that $x(t)$ is bounded.

I have no idea how to attack this problem, could it be that $x(t)$ is also periodic? Would this help me to prove boundedness? I would appreciate any help and suggestions. Is there a theorem of differential equations I am supposed to apply on this problem?

Let $A(t) \in R^{n\times n}$, $A(t)$ continuous, such that $A(t+1)=A(t)$ for all $t \in R$; if $x(t)$ is a solution defined on $R$ of the system
$x'(t)=A(t)x(t)$ such that $x(1)=-x(0)$, prove that $x(t)$ is bounded.

I have no idea how to attack this problem, could it be that $x(t)$ is also periodic? Would this help me to prove boundedness? I would appreciate any help and suggestions. Is there a theorem of differential equations am I supposed to apply on this problem?

Edition:

With the suggestions, all I could think of was: there is a theorem of existence and uniqueness of ODE that says:

Let $F(t,X):I\times \Omega$, $I \in \mathbb R$ an interval, $\Omega$ an open set in $\mathbb R^n$, $F$ continuos on $t$ and locally Lipschitz on $X$ in $I \times \Omega$ $\implies$ the system $\{X'(t)=F(t,X), X(t_0)=X_0\}$ with $t_0 \in I$ and $X_0 \in \Omega$ always admits a unique solution on $[t_0-\delta,t_o+\delta]$

I am trying to check the hypothesis of the theorem are satisfied in order to use it in the problem. Here, $A(t)x(t)$ is continuous by hypothesis, so $F(t,X)=A(t)x(t)$ is continuous. To be locally lipschitz I would have to prove that there is a constant $L$ such that $||F(t,X)-F(t,Y)||\leq L||X-Y||$, to prove this, I would have to prove that $||A(t)x(t)-A(s)x(s)||\leq L||x(t)-x(s)||$, $L>0$, I don't know how to prove this.

If I could prove that, I am still not so sure what to do next: I think I can prove that if $x(t)$ is periodic and continuous, then it has to be bounded, but I am having problem proving periodicity

Comment: Yes, $x$ is also periodic. Suppose you have $x(t)$ on $[0,1]$; what do you think the solution looks like on $[1,2]$? Can you use properties of this ODE (linearity, and uniqueness given one initial condition) to prove it?

Comment: I've edited my post but I am still having doubts with the exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $t\to x(t+1)$ is also a solution of $x'=Ax$. Look at the initial conditions.

details:

1. $t\to  x(t+1)$ is a solution:
   $$\frac d{dt} [x(t+1)] = x'(t+1) = A'(t+1) x(t+1) = A(t) x(t+1)$$
   because of the chain rule and the periodicity of $A$.
2. $-x(1) = x(0)=: x_0$, and in fact $-x(t+1) = x(t)$, because of the unicity of the solution of the Cauchy problem:
   $$
   x'=Ax\\
   x(0) =  x_0
   $$
   In particular, $x(t+2)=-x(t+1) = x(t)$ and $x$ is 2-periodic. This is a $C^1$ functuion, hence it is continuous and
   $$
   \sup_\Bbb R|x| = \sup_{[0,2]}|x|<\infty
   $$

Comment: I've edited my post, I know that if I can prove that $x(t)$ is periodic and continuous, I can show that it's bounded, I am having problems proving periodicity, I am trying to show what you've suggested, that is, $x(t+1)$ is also a solution, this happens iff $x'(t+1)=A(t+1)x(t+1)$ iff $x'(t+1)=A(t)x(t+1)$, I don't see why this last equality is satisfied

Comment: and also, I don't see why periodicity would imply boundedness

Comment: I wrote everything.